# Nodejs - How do I identify wheather the user from Android OS or IOS in nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js

What I want is Identify the user then redirect from backend to some url.

```
app.get('/someurl', function (req, res, next) {

if(android OS){
res.redirect("https://playstore")
}else{
res.redirect("https://appstore")
}
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ua-parser-js package.
`npm install ua-parser-js`
From there you can follow the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js).
Or do the following:

```
const parser = require("ua-parser-js")
app.get('/someurl', function (req, res, next) {
  if(parser(req.headers["user-agent"]).getOS().name === "Android[-x86]") {
    res.redirect("https://playstore")
  } else{
    res.redirect("https://appstore")
  }  
})
```

Comment: Do we need to pass user-agent in headers from the frontend? or it will automatically add it?

Comment: Should be send automatically by the browser.